# Writing command line tool with node

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a command line tool with node (following [these instructions](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/03/node-command-line-tool/)).

So I add "bin" to package.json file

```
"bin": {
  "test": "./index.js"
}
```

Created index.js file

```
#!usr/bin/env node
console.log('test');
```

And I use `$ sudo npm link`.

Finally I try to run it via terminal but I'm getting `-bash: /usr/local/bin/test: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think npm link is needed in this case; you normally would use it to connect a module from your file system that you might otherwise pull in via the npm install command.

Your shebang syntax looks off to me, though, missing the leading slash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: It seems that was the problem. I use npm link by following the tutorial I mentioned. I don't know if there is another way to create a command line tool via node.

Comment: What I'm saying about npm link is that it's not directly involved with making a command line tool, it's ghe logical equivalent of npm install but for local modules on your hard drive that you've not published to the npm repository.

Answer (score 0):

`npm link` links the module locally. For your bin, it means that the binary is installed into `node_modules/.bin/` (if i recall fine).

To link a package globally, you should use the `--local` arg.

`npm link . --local`